# What should I do to display curl progress in the Jenkins console?

Tags: jenkins, curl, output, jenkins-groovy

I'm running following code in Jenkins:

```
node('BuildNode') {
    sh '''
        rm -f tmp_file > /dev/null
        curl \
          -k \
          "https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04.2/ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso?_ga=2.57278633.244943105.1679993691-1161364338.1679993691" \
          -o tmp_file \
          -L
    '''
}
```

The output of this command is not displayed in the Jenking console until the download process is complete.

UPD. BTW, if to use wget instead - Jenkins console prints progress information.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the `wget` option was not valid because at Jenkins machine it was not installed.

I was trying to get downloaded an artefact from my Artifactory, and the process took from seconds to several minutes depending on the size of the file to be downloaded.

In order to get the progress with `curl`, first I tried with the [unbuffer](https://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) and with the [stdbuf](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stdbuf.1.html) both without success (for some reason Jenkins still do not update the log) I have done a workaround with:

```
sh "curl -Sf --progress-bar -O '$fileURL' & pid=\$! && while kill -0 \$pid 2> /dev/null; do echo -n ''; sleep 60; done"
```

- `curl -Sf --progress-bar -O '$fileURL'` is just the curl command to download the $fileURL
- `& pid=\$!` I get the ProcessID for the curl command and store it at the pid variable
- `&& while kill -0 \$pid 2> /dev/null; do echo -n ''; sleep 30; done"` Then I ran a loop that will be running until the curl command got finished

Whit this workaround I must adjust the `sleep 30` time, because in case the file is small and took just seconds to download, this will force me waiting the whole 30 secs. But if I set to a too much small seconds value, Jenkins will be printing too much weird `echo` and `sleep` commands.

[image]

This solution is a bit ugly at logs, but working for my usecase that was just getting information about the progress of the download at the Jenkins log, in order to avoid the user get desperate thinking that job got hanged.

EDIT: Just discovered that the `echo -n ''` is not needed in my case, I use it because I was thinking that Jenkins needs some new-line to print.